# running NAMD on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

When I wanted to run NAMD on 32-bit Ubuntu 15.10, I encountered the following error:

```
bash: /home/nikoot/Documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP/namd2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

output of `ls -l namd2`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nikoot nikoot 18835882 دسامب 21 2015 /home/nikoot
```

output of `file namd2`

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: could you please enter the directory where the file is located, do `ls -l namd2` and `file namd2` and edit your question to include the output. Also, is your system 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run the commands (ls -l namd2 and file namd2), it gives the following answer: No such file or directory. However, the file (namd2) is located at home/documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP.  the operating system of my computer (OS) is 32 bit. Thank you in advance for your time and consideration. regards, Nader Nekoubin

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ls -l ~/Documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP/namd2` and then  `file ~/Documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP/namd2`

Comment: it gives the following answer in the response of first command:  -rwxr-xr-x 1 nikoot nikoot 18835882 دسامب 21  2015 /home/nikoot/Documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP/namd2
Also, it gives the following answer in the response of second command: /home/nikoot/Documents/NAMD_2.11_Linux-x86_64-TCP/namd2: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped

Comment: what is the output of `getconf LONG_BIT` ?

Comment: 32. Should I install ubuntu 64 to fix this problem?

Comment: Either get & install a 32-bit version of the program (easiest/best option), install a 64-bit kernel and boot it or install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu (if your system can handle it)

Comment: You're very welcome but please let's not leave the question like this as it will still show up on the site as 'unanswered' and it is messy - I edited and wrote an answer... you could accept my answer (suggest edit if needed) and then we can delete all these comments?

Comment: I checked and the downloaded software is both for 32 and 64 versions (Linux-x86_64); I supposed that x86 means 32. Therefore, how I can fix this problem since I downloaded the right version? In addition, how I can accept your answer? Thank you for reading and answering my messages.

Comment: x86_64 is for 64-bit - the binary is 64-bit and will not run in your 32-bit system. If there is another executable binary in the directory that is 32-bit, it will run, otherwise, download a version for 32-bit (x86 without _64) from the site. Here's [how to accept](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) but let's solve your problem first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a 32-bit version of the application for your 32-bit system. I see on the [download page of the site](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Development/Download/download.cgi?PackageName=NAMD) there are x86 versions for 32-bit architecture, although these are older.

If your system can handle it, you can install a 64-bit kernel or 64-bit Ubuntu version (time to upgrade from 15.10 ;) ), then you will be able to run the 64-bit version of NAND.